# Difference between <pre> tag and .well class in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I've been learning HTML and CSS and I just started bootstrap.
I've seen what `pre` tag does. It seems that in bootstrap ".well" does the same and I couldn't tell the difference.
So I appreciate who helps.

Sorry for my English :)

Comment: It seems that pre tag in bootstrap is not styled as it should be: https://code.rohitink.com/2015/05/17/solution-tag-bootstrap-breaking-every-word/  And, yes, you have noticed similar, but not exactly the same styling for .well class... However, point of pre tag is to keep spaces and line breaks, bootstrap styling defeats that purpose, it seems...